# Fixing opacity of content inside div

Tags: html, css

I have a div that has a background image but has 50% opacity.

Now I have a div that is child and I want what every the content it has to have 100% opacity. You can see in the snipplet headings and textbox and button has less opacity.

Can anyone help how to fix this thing? I tried to apply opacity 100% to child but it didn't work.

```css
/* CSS to be fixed*/

#home_div
{ 
 background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/1/1e/Shoppers_on_Dundas%2C_near_Yonge.jpg/1200px-Shoppers_on_Dundas%2C_near_Yonge.jpg");
 opacity: 0.5;
    filter: alpha(opacity=50);
 /*background-color: #0050A0;*/
 background-color: lightgrey;
 padding-top: 200px;
 color: white;
 padding-bottom: 200px;
 height: 100%;
}
#home_div_content
{
 opacity: 1.0;
    filter: alpha(opacity=100);
 text-align: center;

}
 #header
 {
  height: 70px;
  border-bottom: 4px solid lightgrey;
 }
 #header_content
 {
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 80px;
 }
 .brandmark
 {
  margin-top: -20px;
 }
 .link_to a
 {
  color: #0050A0 !important;
 }
.featured_div
{
 display: none;
}

.featured_close_anchor, .featured_anchor_close
{
 text-align: center;
}
#heading, #tag_line
{
 top: -300px;
   position:relative;
   color: #0050A0;
}
#search
{
 border-radius: 0 !important;
 border-color: #0050A0 !important;
 width: 60%;
height: 35px;
padding: 8px 15px;
color: #0050A0;   /* change  color of text to be typed inside search box */
font-size: 13px;
line-height: 20px;
background-color: transparent;
border: 1px solid #ccc;
-webkit-box-shadow: none;
box-shadow: none;
}
.btn-custom {
color: #FFFFFF;            
background-color: #0050A0;   /* change  button color */
border-radius: 0!important;    /* button border radius */
padding: 5px 11px;              /* Button size change*/
margin-top: -3.5px;
border-top: 2px solid #0050A0;
border-bottom: 3px solid #0050A0;
margin-left: -3px;
}

.btn-custom:hover{
background-color:#9AC94B; /* change  button color on hover */
border-radius: 0!important;

}
.left_categories
{
 padding-top: 5px;
 padding-bottom: 5px;
 margin-bottom: 1px;
 border-left: 4px solid #0050A0;

}
.left_categories:hover
{

 border-top: 1px solid lightgrey;
 border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
 border-left: 4px solid #E5002B;
}
.active_category
{
 background-color: #0050A0;
 color: white !important;
 border-left: 4px solid #E5002B;
}
.search_section
{
 margin-top: 30px;
}
a
{
 text-decoration: none !important;
}


.flash_nav
{
 height: 90px;
 border: 0 !important;
 background-color: #283442;
}

.gradient
{
 background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, white 0%, white 45%, #12A8E0 85%, #0050A0 100%);
}

.flash_navbar a
{
 color: black !important;
}

.search_form
{
 width: 70%;
}

.nav_form
{
 border-radius: 0;
 margin-top: 27px;
}

#searchBar
{
 border-color: #0050A0;
}

#searchButton
{
 background-color: #0050A0;
 color: white;
 border: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="home_div">
  <div class="container" id="home_div_content">
    <h1 id="heading">Find your product!</h1>
    <h4 id="tag_line">Search what you are looking for.</h4>
    <form method="GET" action="/product/search">
      <input type="text" name="product" id="search" placeholder="Enter product name" class="searchTextBox" />
      <button type="submit" id="quick-search" class="btn btn-custom"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search custom-glyph-color"></span></button>
    </form>
    <br />
    <a href="#" class="featured_anchor">view <i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i> featuring</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/7yvr5bvn/1/)

Comment: The content has 100% opacity. Do you mean the background?

Comment: @SankarshMakam I want to have the background image having 50% opacity only.

Comment: the id `home_div_content` is already at 1 opacity. and the bg is at 0.5 opacity. You said 'It didn't work'. Yes, it did. The content is at 1 opacity.

Comment: But look heading and textbox aren't clear

Comment: Here some example https://codepen.io/ncerminara/pen/eFzJI/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An opacity rule will always affect child/descendant elements since they are part of the parent, and the rule says the parent should be 50% opacity.

To get round this, use a pseudo element and give *that* reduced opacity rather than the parent.

HTML

```
<div id='outer'>
  <div id='inner'></div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#outer { width: 200px; height: 200px; position: relative; padding: 2em; }
#outer::before { content: ''; position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; width: 100%; height: 100%; background: red; opacity: .5; z-index: -1; }
#inner { width: 100%; height: 100%; background: blue; }
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7yvr5bvn/).

Comment: I admire your explanation. I tried css on 
`#home_div::before` but it didn't have any affect

Comment: Hmm, well the concept demonstrably works, as you can see in the Fiddle. Try setting up a Fiddle then people can jump in.

Comment: There you go check fiddle

Comment: You've forgotten to remove the old opacity instructions on the parent container. Now you have pseudo content, you don't need those. Please consider an upvote if you appreciate the efforts.